# how to get array of objects in object itself in php through json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am developing on-line property booking site for tourist
here is my table as where i am retriving data from database as

`PROPERTYiD      ACCOMODATIONTYPE   AVAILABLEROOMS
    ----------------------------------------------- 
                    |                   |
kalyan appartment   |       1BHK        |    5
kalyan appartment   |        2 BHK      |    6

BHARAT tourist      |       VILLA       |    2
BHARAT tourist      |        2 BHK      |    3
sneh tourist hotel  |        2hk room   |    1`

My json is

```
{"rows":[{"propertyId":"kalyan appartment","cell":[{"available_rooms":"5","AccomodationTypeName":"1bhk"}]},{"propertyId":"kalyan appartment","cell":[{"available_rooms":"6","AccomodationTypeName":"2bhk"}]},{"propertyId":"BHARAT tourist","cell":[{"available_rooms":"2","AccomodationTypeName":"villa"}]},{"propertyId":"BHARAT tourist","cell":[{"available_rooms":"3","AccomodationTypeName":"2bhk"}]},{"propertyId":"sneh tourist hotel","cell":[{"available_rooms":"1","AccomodationTypeName":"2hk room"}]}]}
```

Here my json is displying available rooms per accommodation type but i want my json should be (no of accomodation & their available rooms per property id )means it should give json as-

```
kalyan appartment   |   [{"accomodation type":"1BHK","available_rooms":"5"},
                          {"accomodation type":"2BHK","available_rooms":"6"}]

BHARAT tourist      |   [{"accomodation type":"VILLA","available_rooms":"2"},
                         {"accomodation type":"2BHK","available_rooms":"3"}]

sneh tourist hotel  |  [{"accomodation type":" 2hk room ","available_rooms":"1"}]
```

My php code is

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {

    if ($i == 0) {
        $propertyId = $row ['propertyId'];
    }

    $j = 0;
    $propertyInfo = array ();

    if ($propertyId == $row ['propertyId']) {
        for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j ++) {
            $propertyInfo [$j] ['roomAvailable'] = $row ['roomidCount'];
            $propertyInfo [$j] ['AccomodationTypeName'] = $row ['AccomodationTypeName'];
            break;
        }
    } else {
        $propertyInfo [0] ['roomAvailable'] = $row ['roomidCount'];
        $propertyInfo [0] ['AccomodationTypeName'] = $row ['AccomodationTypeName'];
    }
    $responce->rows [$i] ['propertyId'] = $row ['propertyId'];
    $responce->rows [$i] ['cell'] = $propertyInfo;
    $i ++;
    $propertyId = $row ['propertyId'];
}
echo json_encode ( $responce );
```

Comment: Could you explain what result do you expecting after encoding response to json? Your example `kalyan appartment   |   [{"accomodation type":"..."}]` is not a valid json.

Comment: `{"rows":[{"propertyId":"kalyan appartment","cell":[{"AccomodationTypeName":"1bhk","available_rooms":"5"},{"AccomodationTypeName":"2bhk","available_rooms":"6"}]},{"propertyId":"BHARAT tourist","cell":[{"AccomodationTypeName":"VILLA","available_rooms":"2"},{"AccomodationTypeName":"2bhk","available_rooms":"3"}]},{"propertyId":"sneh tourist hotel","cell":[{"AccomodationTypeName":"2hk room","available_rooms":"1"}]}]}`

Comment: if there is something wrong in expected json,please correct me